# MyBatis with SQL Server: SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() does not set the assigned key

Tags: sql-server, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis 3.4.5 with Java 8 and SQL Server 2014.

When inserting a new object, I cannot make the `insert` method set the assigned identity key, the `id` field is left with the `null` value.

This is my setup:

```
public class TestMapper {
    @Insert({ "insert into TEST (VAL_INT) values " +
          "(#{valInt,jdbcType=INTEGER})" })
    @SelectKey(statement = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", keyProperty = "id", before = false, resultType = Integer.class)
    int insert(Test record);
}

public class Test {

    private Integer id;
    // ...  other fields and getters/setters follow
}

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VAL_INT] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TEST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC)
```

I have checked that the `setId()` is indeed called after the insert, but with the `null` value. It all happens as if `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returned `NULL` - it works if I run the insert manually in the Management Studio.

(There are some similar questions, but they not exactly identical, they are old and they do not really provide some satisfactory answer).

Comment: I would combine it with query' " select val from table; select scope_ident()"

Comment: I'm not sure how that would play with mybatis. How would you modify my code?

Comment: Well good question. Call a stored proc and return it via an output parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I responded to your mybatis user list email but here's how you can do this:

In xml I use:

```
<insert id="insertFoo" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id">
    insert into TEST (VAL_INT) values (#{valInt,jdbcType=INTEGER})
</insert>
```

In java annotations that would be:

```
@Insert({ "insert into TEST (VAL_INT) values (#{valInt,jdbcType=INTEGER})" })
@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty="id", keyColumn="id")
```

Answer (score 0):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() shows the most recent identifier created within that scope. But you have two separate calls to the database, meaning you have two scopes, and in the second scope when you try to get the ID you haven't created an ID yet to get for that scope.

To fix this, you need to combine these into a single call to the database that inserts the data and returns the new key.

Comment: "you have two separate calls to the database, meaning you have two scopes" That is a guess or you can be sure of that? "To fix this, you need to combine these into a single call to the database..." That does not seems easy to do in the MyBatis way... What puzzles me is that this is the standard recommended way, see eg http://www.mybatis.org/generator/configreference/generatedKey.html - I wonder if this could ever worked?